# Not able to scrape more than 90 pages at a time using Curl and php?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have created a **scraper** for one of my client, the scraper is mainly used to crawl few of the partner websites and get the data. The scraper works brilliantly till 90 pages and once it reaches 90 pages, it keeps **scraping** the same page again and again. I am really confused as in why this is happening.

can someone help me out with this?

```
function getFlightCharges() {
$requestHeaders = requestHeaderProperties ();
$sql = 'select * from F_charge where enabled = 0';
$details = DatabaseHandler::GetAll ( $sql );
foreach ( $details as $detail ) {
    $link = $detail ['product_link'];
    $id = $detail ['id'];
    $url = $link;
    $referer = 'Referer: example.com/';
    $requestHeaders [] = $referer;
    $html = getHTMLContentFromURL ( $url, $requestHeaders );
    foreach ( $html->find ( '.no-touch' ) as $e ) {
        foreach ( $e->find ( '.content-well' ) as $e1 ) {
            foreach ( $e1->find ( '.price' ) as $prices ) {
                $pricee = strip_tags ( $prices->innertext );
            }
            foreach ( $e1->find ( '.article-body' ) as $desc ) {
                $description = strip_tags ( $desc->innertext );
            }
        }
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO price_data(product_price) VALUES (:product_price)";
    $params = array (':product_price' => $price);
    DatabaseHandler::Execute ( $sql, $params );     
}

DatabaseHandler::Close ();
}
```

So here is the functions that gets the link of the partner website, gets the current price and updates my database. It is working good until the 89th or 90th page. But soon after that it gets stuck in 90th page and keeps scraping and updating it in the database

Comment: it gets stuck in the next page. Its not always 90th page. Sometimes its 88th, 89th or 90th. Is there any curl timeout that might get it stuck to the same page??

Comment: try to add `set_time_limit (0)`

Comment: I can't get the logic of your code. You do a lot of effort to retrieve information into variables that are immediately overwritten or even not used at all. You keep appending values to `$requestHeaders` for no obvious reason (it's impossible to know what it's used for because `getHTMLContentFromURL()` is undisclosed). In any case you need to do some **basic debugging**. The only thing that instructs your code to switch pages is the outer loop that comes from a database query: if you get the same result again and again the first thing I'd suspect is that your table has tons of dupes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález the table has all unique data. and the getHTMLContentFromURL() is a curl function that gets the html raw data for parsing. and in the above code every variable used has a use case. I did do the basic debugging, but was of no use as the code works brilliantly till the 89th or 90th page. It is only after that the crawler gets stuck to the same page.

Comment: @RuthRogers, do you handle cookie in `getHTMLContentFromURL()`? Web sites might turn on scrape protection based on cookie value (its absence actually)...

Comment: @IgorSavinkin yes I do handle cookies. I have the complete request header.

Comment: @RuthRogers, have you tired the solution that I've proposed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> But soon after that it gets stuck in 90th page and keeps scraping and updating it in the database

Basically each php script is [limited with a time it runs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Some servers limit it to 30 sec. So if you process 90 pages, you might get out of this script run time limit.

The solution for you would be:

1. Limit pages number access per script run.
2. Make `cron` command to execute your script on schedule.
3. Since you invoke script at different time, you should add time markers into db tables to save time mark of when a record has been updated last time.

Comment: The OP described the exact opposite: the script doesn't time out but it runs forever.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, *But soon after that it gets stuck in 90th page and keeps scraping and updating it in the database* - how does he know that script works if the same page is under its extraction. Script might not run and OP thinks that script runs updating the same records...